# Why does this script show an error on one server and not another with the same OS and shell version?

Tags: bash, tomcat9

I have the following tomcat init script installed on multiple web servers.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# description: Apache Tomcat init script
# processname: tomcat
# chkconfig: 234 20 80
#
#
# Copyright (C) 2014 Miglen Evlogiev
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
# the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software
# Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later
# version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
# FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with
# this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# Initially forked from: gist.github.com/valotas/1000094
# Source: gist.github.com/miglen/5590986


#Location of JAVA_HOME (bin files)
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest

#Add Java binary files to PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

#CATALINA_HOME is the location of the bin files of Tomcat
export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat9

#CATALINA_BASE is the location of the configuration files of this instance of Tomcat
export CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat9

#TOMCAT_USER is the default user of tomcat
export TOMCAT_USER=tomcat

#TOMCAT_USAGE is the message if this script is called without any options
TOMCAT_USAGE="Usage: $0 {\e[00;32mstart\e[00m|\e[00;31mstop\e[00m|\e[00;31mkill\e[00m|\e[00;32mstatus\e[00m|\e[00;31mrestart\e[00m}"

#SHUTDOWN_WAIT is wait time in seconds for java proccess to stop
SHUTDOWN_WAIT=20

tomcat_pid() {
        echo `ps -fe | grep $CATALINA_BASE | grep -v grep | tr -s " "|cut -d" " -f2`
}

start() {
  pid=$(tomcat_pid)
  if [ -n "$pid" ]
  then
    echo -e "\e[00;31mTomcat is already running (pid: $pid)\e[00m"
  else
    # Start tomcat
    echo -e "\e[00;32mStarting tomcat\e[00m"
    #ulimit -n 100000
    #umask 007

        if [ `user_exists $TOMCAT_USER` = "1" ]
        then
                sudo -u $TOMCAT_USER $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
        else
                echo -e "\e[00;31mTomcat user $TOMCAT_USER does not exists. Starting with $(id)\e[00m"
                sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
        fi
        status
  fi
  return 0
}

status(){
          pid=$(tomcat_pid)
          if [ -n "$pid" ]
            then echo -e "\e[00;32mTomcat is running with pid: $pid\e[00m"
          else
            echo -e "\e[00;31mTomcat is not running\e[00m"
            return 3
          fi
}

terminate() {
    echo -e "\e[00;31mTerminating Tomcat\e[00m"
    kill -9 $(tomcat_pid)
}

stop() {
  pid=$(tomcat_pid)
  if [ -n "$pid" ]
  then
    echo -e "\e[00;31mStoping Tomcat\e[00m"
    echo "DEBUG LINE 95"

      sudo -u tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh

    let kwait=$SHUTDOWN_WAIT
    count=0;
    until [ `ps -p $pid | grep -c $pid` = '0' ] || [ $count -gt $kwait ]
    do
      echo -n -e "\n\e[00;31mwaiting for processes to exit\e[00m";
      sleep 1
      let count=$count+1;
    done

    if [ $count -gt $kwait ]; then
      echo -n -e "\n\e[00;31mkilling processes didn't stop after $SHUTDOWN_WAIT seconds\e[00m"
      terminate
    fi
  else
    echo -e "\e[00;31mTomcat is not running\e[00m"
  fi

  return 0
}

user_exists(){
        if id -u $1 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "1"
        else
                echo "0"
        fi
}

case $1 in
    start)
      start
    ;;
    stop)
      stop
    ;;
    restart)
      stop
      start
    ;;
    status)
        status
        exit $?
    ;;
    kill)
        terminate
    ;;
    *)
        echo -e $TOMCAT_USAGE
    ;;
esac
```

Both servers are running the same Amazon Linux:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

Both servers run the same bash version:

```
[ec2-user@host ~]$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.46(2)-release
```

On one server, the script correctly sets the PID, creates the PID file, and starts Tomcat.  When I stop Tomcat, it stops successfully.

On the other server, the script sets *two* PIDs, does not create the PID file, and starts Tomcat.  When I stop Tomcat, I get this error:

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat9: line 100: [: =: unary operator expected
```

I know how to correct this, and have, but why in the world is the behavior different on two hosts that are, for all intents and purposes, identical?  They were both provisioned using the same Ansible playbook and roles and as shown are running the same versions of things across the board.  So what gives?

Comment: I would run this script through `shellcheck.net` first and correcting everything it points out before trying to debug it further.

Comment: Note also that we ask questions that include code to have that code cut down to a [mcve] *before asking*. When you don't know a priori which parts are important, the "Tricks for Trimming" guidance at http://sscce.org/ is pertinent.

Comment: ...that said, *in general*, `[: =: unary operator expected` means that something that was expected to emit a value that string-split to a single word instead had no output at all (and the quoting was wrong as http://shellcheck.net/ would show, so we got a syntax error rather than graceful handling).

Comment: To pick on the `user_exists` comparison, the code would be much simpler if written as `user_exists() { id -u "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; }`, and then `if user_exists tomcat; then`; there's no defensible reason to have a `[` command *at all* there.

Comment: Can you confirm that this single line is the only output you get from the script, and that there are no additional error messages like `Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...`?

Comment: Sorry folks, I've got it figured out.  My question isn't necessarily about why the script is having problems (after all, I can debug the shell script) but why it would behave differently on two servers with the same versions of bash and operating systems.  What I failed to realize is that the tomcat version is two patches off between the servers (9.0.14 vs 9.0.16);  such a minor revision difference shouldn't cause this type of issue but such is life.

Comment: For next time, it would probably help if your init script catches the case of multiple PIDs matching, stops whatever it is doing and prints a self-explanatory error message.

Comment: @sborsky Had I authored this script, things would be different, certainly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is line 100:

```
until [ `ps -p $pid | grep -c $pid` = '0' ] || [ $count -gt $kwait ]
```

Apparently process $pid is not running: the grep output is *empty* and the shell sees this:

```
until [  = '0' ] || [ $count -gt $kwait ]
```

Since the `[` command now has only 2 arguments, it emits an error about `=` being an invalid unary operator.

You need to quote all the arguments, and I'd recommend using `$()` instead of backticks:

```
until [ "$(ps -p $pid | grep -c $pid)" = '0' ] || [ $count -gt $kwait ]
# ..... ^^^ ....................... ^^
```

Comment: You might want to investigate `pgrep` in place of `ps | grep`

Comment: ...the OP should really investigate using a real process supervision system (systemd, runit, upstart, launchd, etc) instead of SysV-style init scripts in the first place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Unfortunately these servers are, for the time being, stuck with Amazon Linux.  Of course I'd like to move to Amazon Linux 2 which supports systemd but we can't always get what we want.